# mail() php отправка html письма

Tags: php

Как можно отправить через mail() php письмо html, если html код символов 900-1500?

```
mail($to, $subject, $text, $headers);
```

в $text='длинный html код '

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: в переменную не помешается весь код  а делать 30 переменных как-то не хочется

Comment: Что значит «не помещается код»? Вам неудобно писать его в одну строку? В PHP есть [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Может проще html вынести в отдельный файл, и загружать его в переменную перед функцией mail? `$text = file_get_contents('./message_file.html');`

Answer (score 1):

Вот вызов метода

```
$file = false;
$email = "email";
$theme = "theme";
$body = "body";

SendMail(array($email, $theme, $body), null, 'text/html', $file);
```

и сам **метод**

```
function SendMail ($letter, $data = '', $letter_type = 'text/plain', &$file = false) 
{   
    $is_file = false;

    $mailheaders = "From: DEMO<demo@demo.com>";     

    $semi_rand = md5(time());
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";                             
    $mailheaders .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";    

    $body = $letter[2];
    if (is_array($data)) {
        while (list($from, $to) = each($data)) {
            $body = str_replace($from, $to, $body);
        }
    }                   

    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: $letter_type; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $body . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    if($file !== false) {
        if(@is_file($file[0])) {                        
            $handler = fopen($file[0], "rb");               
            if($handler !== false) {
                $fdata = fread($handler, filesize($file[0]));
                fclose($handler);
                $is_file = true;
            }
        } else {
            $fdata = $file[0];
            $is_file = true;
        }

        if($is_file) {          
            $fdata = chunk_split(base64_encode($fdata));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"".$file[1]."\"\n" . 
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".$file[1]."\"\n" . 
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $fdata . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
        }
    }       

    mail ($letter[0], $letter[1], $message, $mailheaders);
}
```